# How can I compile a ColorFunction with Blend?

Tags: compile, color

```
f1 = {Max[4 # - 1.5, -4 # + 4.5], Min[4 # - 0.5, -4 # + 3.5], 
 Min[4 # + 0.5, -4 # + 2.5]} &;

cf1 = Compile[{{z, _Real}}, {Max[4 z - 1.5, -4 z + 4.5], 
    Min[4 z - 0.5, -4 z + 3.5], Min[4 z + 0.5, -4 z + 2.5]}];

ArrayPlot[Table[x y, {x, -200, 200}, {y, -200, 200}], 
  ColorFunction -> (RGBColor@f1@# &)] // Timing
```

I know how to compile the `ColorFunction` f1, but I dont't know whether `f2` can be compiled.

```
f2 = Blend[{{0, RGBColor[0, 0, 9/16]}, {1/9, Blue}, {23/63, Cyan},{13/21,Yellow}, 
{47/63, Orange}, {55/63, Red}, {1, RGBColor[1/2, 0, 0]}}, #] &;
```

Comment: See [this list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101/5)... `Blend` is not on that list, which means you can't compile it unless you re-implement `Blend` using functions on that list (which shouldn't be hard, since it's just linear interpolation).

Comment: Why do you need to compile a `ColorFunction` it shouldn't be too slow...

Comment: As rm, notes, `Blend[]` internally performs linear interpolation over the RGB color space. See the linked question for compiled functions for linear interpolation.